# Jar file corrupting after PHP upload

Tags: php

my name is Luaq. I am developing a website for myself and my projects, and I am wondering why it is my jar files keep corrupting when I upload them (`move_uploaded_file()`). The binary to my text files and nearly everything else that I have tried has worked. But, when I download and try to drag the .jar file into [luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten) it gives me this:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

I've also noticed that upon uploading the file, when I use `ls` in the VPS terminal the .jar file is red (unlike the others which are green).

Here is the code for uploading:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']) && isset($_POST['folderName'])){

$file = $_FILES['uploadedFile'];
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/".$_POST['folderName'].'/'.basename($file['name']);
print($path);

move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path); }
```

When it uploads it keeps the same file size, that doesn't change. Anyone that can help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Luaq

Comment: Can you do `ls -l` on the file? Check the permissions and ownership to see if it is readable by user who gets the error.

Comment: @mike.k I typed this in the terminal and I got this in return: `-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 13330 Jun 27 20:52`

Comment: those `r`s mean it is readable by anyone, as long as the folders it is under are also readable. The error may be more in luyten than PHP. Try to get the MD5 or other hash on the file before and after upload. PHP has a function `md5_file()` and in Linux you probably have `md5sum` available in the shell